# Issue with constructor call or JFrame

Tags: java, constructor, jframe, call

I have a class called Frame that extends JFrame and implements ActionListener and when:

```
    if(e.getSource() == addSpell){
            ArrayList<Spell> temp = new ArrayList<Spell>();
            for(Spell spell: SpellList.getSpellList()){
                if(spell.getType().equals(user.getType())){
                temp.add(spell);
                }

            new SpellArraySorter(temp, this);
            this.setVisible(false);
    }
```

is called, either new SpellArraySorter() is called 6 times, or the constructor creates 6 jFrames.

```
public class SpellArraySorter implements ActionListener{

private JButton help;
private JButton enter;
private JFrame frame;
private JTextField level;
private JTextField levelfill;
private JTextField name;
private JTextField namefill;
private JTextField dmg1;
private JTextField dmg2;
private JTextField dmgfill1;
private JTextField dmgfill2;
private Frame f;

private ArrayList<Spell> changedSpellArray;

public SpellArraySorter(ArrayList<Spell> spellArray, Frame f){
        this.f = f;
        changedSpellArray = new ArrayList<Spell>(spellArray);

        frame = new JFrame();
        level = new JTextField();
        levelfill = new JTextField();
        name = new JTextField();
        namefill = new JTextField();
        dmg1 = new JTextField();
        dmg2 = new JTextField();
        dmgfill1 = new JTextField();
        dmgfill2 = new JTextField();

        help = new JButton("HELP");
        enter = new JButton("enter");

        frame.setLayout(null);
        frame.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 300));
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

        level.setBounds(30, 35, 100, 20);
        levelfill.setBounds(180, 35, 100, 20);
        name.setBounds(30, 90, 100, 20);
        namefill.setBounds(180, 90, 100, 20);
        dmg1.setBounds(30, 145, 100, 20);
        dmg2.setBounds(200, 145, 20, 20);
        dmgfill1.setBounds(180, 145, 20, 20);
        dmgfill2.setBounds(220, 145, 20, 20);

        level.setText("Level of Spell: ");
        name.setText("name of Spell: ");
        dmg1.setText("Damage of Spell: ");
        dmg2.setText("d");

        level.setEditable(false);
        name.setEditable(false);
        dmg1.setEditable(false);
        dmg2.setEditable(false);

        help.setBounds(30, 215, 100, 20);
        enter.setBounds(180, 215, 100, 20);

        help.addActionListener(this);
        enter.addActionListener(this);

        frame.add(level);
        frame.add(levelfill);
        frame.add(name);
        frame.add(namefill);
        frame.add(dmg1);
        frame.add(dmg2);
        frame.add(dmgfill1);
        frame.add(dmgfill2);
        frame.add(help);
        frame.add(enter);

        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
```

I cannot for the life of me figure out why,  but every time I click the addSpell JButton on the Frame class's GUI, I have 6 JFrames appear of the class SpellArraySorter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if you copied your code snippet wrong or not, but this looks like normal behavior to me.

This line is causing your issue:

`new SpellArraySorter(temp, this);`

The reason is because you call the above line while still inside your FOR loop. So for every item in your `SpellList` you are creating a new JFrame when you use `new SpellArraySorter(temp, this);`

Try this:

```
if(e.getSource() == addSpell){
        ArrayList<Spell> temp = new ArrayList<Spell>();
        for(Spell spell: SpellList.getSpellList()){
            if(spell.getType().equals(user.getType())){
                temp.add(spell);
            }
            //LINES MOVED FROM HERE
        }
        //LINES MOVED TO HERE
        new SpellArraySorter(temp, this);
        this.setVisible(false);
```

Comment: I had accidentally deleted the closing bracket, and missed that error at least three of four times. Thank you!